# ODATA $expand and $select queries in url

Tags: url, odata

Yes, I know, this question is always asked. But I looked for answers to my problem, and everything I've seen is the same explanation, but it still doesn't work for me. Explanations.

For example on the Northwind service (that I use to train because it is simple, before using my job's service) : https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

If I do

- https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories
- https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$select=CategoryName
- https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$expand=Products

It works.

**BUT** if I want to do : https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$expand=Products($select=ProductName) (since there is a ProductName property in Products) ... It doesn't work. I have the error : **Syntax error at position 9**. That "position 9" corresponds to the first parenthesis.

However, all I have seen on http://odata.org/documentation and on StackOverflow's forum says it should be something like that. What do I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found. In odata v2, we need to expand the entity we want to display and then select out of parenthesis with the path relative to the basis entity.

Example :

https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$expand=Products&$select=Products/ProductName

It is not so weird after all...

Answer (score 3):

This is supported, you refer to an old sample service which is v2, you can do request like this one which is protocol v4 based,
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ax34fkajuohvk1aw5pjzykjk))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Trips($select=TripId,Name)

It works well.

BTW, this sample service is built on some technology which is in maintained mode, if you start to build a new service, we will recommend to use RESTier, refer to odata.github.io/RESTier/ or use OData web Api library, refer to odata.github.io/WebApi

Comment: Thank you but actually, my job's odata service is probably V2, this type of request doesn't work... That's why I train on Northwind V2 :/

Comment: IMO, you should train against your actual API, especially for simple non-affecting `GET` requests, you'll get more out of it, odata.org is just an example implementation and does not fully implement all query options supported by the specification. This is especially true of v4, but could just as easily apply to the previous versions.